# How to change logo of MS Dynamic CRM 2013 comes in Left side top of the form

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2013

I wants to replacethe logo of MS Dynamic CRM 2013 with our company logo.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong you want to change the logo i.e you want to display
`Your Company Name` instead of `Microsoft Dynamics CRM`

you can do that look at the following link:

[Change CRM 2013 logo to your custom logo](http://mscrmhacks.com/change-crm-2013-logo/)

If you want to change the `favicon` to `your company icon/logo` look at the following link:

[Changing the CRM Icon](http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/davidsutton/2010/06/13/Changing_the_CRM_Icon.aspx)